# Finding the eigenvectors for the following matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following matrix: $$\left(\begin{matrix}-1-\lambda&124&154\\0&-338-\lambda&420\\0&-280&348-\lambda\\\end{matrix}\right)$$

I must find the eigenvector when $\lambda = -2$

I have tried the following:

$$\left(\begin{matrix}-1-\left(-2\right)&124&154\\0&-338-\left(-2\right)&420\\0&-280&348-\left(-2\right)\\\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\\z\\\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\0\\0\\\end{matrix}\right)
$$

Taking the matrix multiplication:
$$=\left(\begin{matrix}x+124y+154z=0\\0x-336y+420z=0\\0x-280y+350z=0\\\end{matrix}\right)$$

Row reducing the matrix to get a simplified form:

Steps:

1. R3 + $\frac{5}{6}$R2

$$=\left(\begin{matrix}x+124y+154z=0\\0x-336y+420z=0\\0x+0y+700z=0\\\end{matrix}\right)$$

This would imply that $z=0$, and so $y=0$ and therefore $x=0$, so $\lambda = -2$ is not an eigenvector for the matrix?

Comment: The row reduction you perform is not correct. This is clear as you are summing 2 negative values and getting 0. The other answer gives a correct reduction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these RREF steps

- $R_3: R_3 -\dfrac{5}{6} R_2$
- $R_2: -\dfrac{R_2}{336}$
- $R_1: R_1 -124 R_2$

The RREF result is

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 309 \\
 0 & 1 & -\dfrac{5}{4} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

You can choose the eigenvector as

$$v = (-1236, 5, 4)$$

Comment: I'm having some difficulties trying to get the eigenvector as you did when comparing the steps to my notes. I tried the following: $4y = 5z$, $x = -309z$, however I cannot seem to get what you got.

Comment: From the second equation, we get $$b = (5/4) c$$ From the first equation, we get $$a = -309 c$$ $c$ ends up being a free variable. Choose $c = 4$. Clear?

Comment: Thank you, this is clear to me.